# Making an object out of an image and class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, object

I am currently making a simple target game. 
It works just fine at the moment. But I only have one target.
An image that has a class and a timer assigned. I manipulate
it through this:

```
CGRect player = target.frame;
```

Now I want to have more targets, but I dont want to add 
new classes and images. I just want to clone this one and assign
it to different variables.

Comment: "An image that has a class and a timer assigned?" Explain more, please.

Comment: i have done a timer that runs a class . in that class i check if the image was touched . then i move the image to a random position and add random size . i want to have multiple targets , that i can create and delete . if you play on easy there is only one target on hard there are 5

Answer (score 0):

I don't basically understand what you are trying to achieve by having same targets(with same classes and objects).Anyways you can simply add the target by going to the blue panel in your project signifying a caption 'Target' and there you can right click and select "duplicate target".You will have to build your app.Also under 'Other c flags' add a property and you can access it know which target is running.

Comment: i want to use it the same way you use a structure in c++